# Replacing commas with blank spaces from a read in text file

Tags: python, file, text, replace

```
import os

os.chdir('my directory')
data = open('text.txt', 'r')
data = data.replace(",", " ")
print(data)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: You have to read the data from the file into a string first. Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Don't use `chdir`. Just open the file with `with open(os.path.join(my_directory, 'text.txt'), 'r') as data:`.

Comment: can anyone tell me why I got 4 thumbs down for this Q? Banning my account is useless without a proper explanation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should open files in a `with` statement:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as data:
  plaintext = data.read()

plaintext = plaintext.replace(',', '')
```

the `with` statement ensures that resources are released properly, so you don't have to worry about remembering to close them.

The more substantial thing you were missing is that `data` is a file object, and replace works on strings. `data.read()` returns the string of text in the file.

Comment: thank you! now is there a way to save this updated file that replaces the old one?

Comment: yeah. If you open the file using `with open('text.txt', 'w') as data:` after you've gotten the text and done your modifications, you can then use `data.write(plaintext)` to overwrite the contents of the old file. I recommend looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) at this point to see where you can go from here